# Implementing New button in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have form with one JPanel panel, which is Super for several others. By choosing item from menu, program creates some type of JPanel which I already made and equals it with main panel. Then that panel shows on the form.
Now, I have two questions:

How to implement New button in File menu?

How to hide previous used panel when user chooses something else? It displays another panel, but under first displayed.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
public class MGeo extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JPanel contentPane, panel;
public PanelGN pgn;
public Panel2D p2dp; 

public MGeo() {
    setTitle("MGeo");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 795, 700);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 395, 26);
    contentPane.add(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mntmNew = new JMenuItem("New");
    mnFile.add(mntmNew);

    JMenu mnIzravnanje = new JMenu("Izravnanje");
    menuBar.add(mnIzravnanje);

    JMenu mnUslovno = new JMenu("Uslovno");
    mnIzravnanje.add(mnUslovno);

    JMenuItem mntmdMreza = new JMenuItem("2D mreza");
    mnUslovno.add(mntmdMreza);

    JMenu mnPosredno = new JMenu("Posredno");
    mnIzravnanje.add(mnPosredno);

    JMenuItem mntmdGeom = new JMenuItem("1D - geom. nivelman");
    mntmdGeom.setActionCommand("GN");
    mntmdGeom.addActionListener(this);
    mnPosredno.add(mntmdGeom);

    JMenuItem mntmdTrig = new JMenuItem("1D - trig. nivelman");
    mnPosredno.add(mntmdTrig);

    JMenuItem mntmdMreza_1 = new JMenuItem("2D mreza");
    mntmdMreza_1.setActionCommand("2Dp");
    mntmdMreza_1.addActionListener(this);
    mnPosredno.add(mntmdMreza_1);

    addButtons(toolBar);
    contentPane.add(toolBar);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    switch((String)e.getActionCommand()){
    case "GN":
        make 'panel' contains pgn (JPanel child)...
        break;
    case "2Dp":
        make 'panel' contains p2dp (JPanel child)...
        break;
    case ...
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see some code? What kind of `panels` are you talking about? Are you using a `JDesktopPane`/`JInternalFrame`? What do you mean hide - you want it to be minimized within the overarching JFrame or to be completely removed until it's selected within the menu again?

Comment: Which part of code do I need to copy? It is quite a long code...
That main (JPanel type) panel is on the JFrame's contentPane (default), and all other panels which need to go on main panel are children (made by me - in separate classes) of JPanel.
@Human, completely removed until it's selected whitin the menu again.

Comment: I suspect you need to do something like Form.getContentPane().removeAll() then add the new JPanel, but we need an SSCCE.

Comment: Sorry, that's no SSCCE.

Comment: @m0skit0 Is it symilar to SSCCE now? I really cannt do it better.

Comment: Don't use a null layout,you don't control things like font metrics or DPI which change the layout requirements of your compnents. Make appropriate use of layout managers. You may also want to look at JFrame#setJMenuBar

Answer (score 3):

> How to implement New button in File menu?

See [JMenu tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) from Oracle tutorials.

> How to hide previous used panel when user chooses something else? It
>   displays another panel, but under first displayed.

[`JPanel#setVisible(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setVisible%28boolean%29)

Comment: not new button, File-New button (for clearing all panels and bringing it in first stage, like program has just started).
I know for this tutorial, but it doesnt helps in this case.

Comment: *"for clearing all panels and bringing it in first stage, like program has just started"* So I was supposed to guess that?

Comment: When program starts, it has menu bar and toolbar. When user chooses something from menu, panel of choose is displayed on frame, too. When user chooses something else from menu, old panel needs to to be removed, and on his place goes new.
I dont know how to explain on other way.